# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError):function is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

I saw a couple of similar posts to this, however, they were all related to Props passed functions. This is somewhate different.

[image]

I'm getting this error, however the function is defined, I made the same import on another jsx file an have no issues calling methods from my class

**SOAP Controller**

```
 class SoapController {
  constructor(segurisignUser) {
    this.segurisignUser = segurisignUser;
    this.passwordDomain = "";
    this.userDomain = "ws_test";
    this.idDomain = "1";
    this.url = "";
  }

      async createUser(user) {
        // ...snip...
  };
}
```

**Login**

```
  const submit = async () => {
    const soapController = new SoapController();
    setDisabled(true);
    setLoading(true);
    const resultado = await soapController.createUser({ email, password, name });


  };
```

Thanks!

Comment: The SoapController code you're showing _is_ the `createUser` function, not a class to build instances of. If that's not a bad paste: don't use `new SoapController()`. And if it is a bad paste, please fix the code you're showing in your post.

Comment: Hi! I didn't want to copy the whole class. Since it's so big

Comment: And we wouldn't want you to, but you _should_ copy the [mcve] class. Even if it's example code, what you show should still make sense (and in this case, calling a function as a constructor, unless it's old legacy code, does not make sense =)

Comment: Done! Hope it's easier to understand now

Comment: It is, but remember the [mcve] tennet: remove things that don't matter. If the createUser function is flagged as "it doesn't exist" then it doesn't matter what's in it and you can replace its entire function content with `// ...snip...`, but to carry that forward: if the error is on `await soapController.createUser` then any line after that is also not necessary, and at that point: now that we're reducing, keep going, there's a ton of code left in your codebase that you can remove to home in on the real problem (and only you can do, we can't do that for you).

Comment: The request for an [mcve] is always to make sure _you run through that exercise_ because forcing yourself to hard-reduce your code (checkout a new branch, and start deleting as much code as you can, hardcoding data that is required and literally just throwing away what isn't) almost always forces you to (re)examine what your code paths do, and 99% of the time lets you find the problem all on your own. With the benefit that once your code fits on a single page and it still fails and you still don't know why: now you have the perfect code to put in a question.

Comment: What do `console.log(soapController)` and `console.log(soapController.createUser)` print?

Comment: @A_A soapController prints the object and soapController.createUser prints undefined